# The following classes could not be instantiated: - androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView and Render problem in android studio

Tags: xml, android-studio, render, android-appcompat, implementation

I have two red errors in my activity_main.xml class, one is "Failed to instantiate one or more classes" and the other is "Render problem". These problem arose after I had updated my android studio IDE from Dolphin | 2021.3.1 to Giraffe | 2022.3.1. I have tried multiple things to try to fix it but nothing is working. Things that I have tried https://9to5answer.com/android-failed-to-instantiate-one-or-more-classes

This is what I'm getting wrong with the render problem but I can't find a way to get rid of the * since I can't find it to begin with.

> java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <*> at index 34: C:\Users\tr\AppData\Local\Temp*
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:177)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:232)
> at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:147)
> at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:69)
> at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderSecurityManager.canonicalize(RenderSecurityManager.java:456)
> at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderSecurityManager.isWritingAllowed(RenderSecurityManager.java:462)
> at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderSecurityManager.checkPermission(RenderSecurityManager.java:720)
> at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.hasCachePermission(ImageIO.java:216)
> at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.createImageInputStream(ImageIO.java:353)
> at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1361)
> at com.android.ninepatch.GraphicsUtilities.loadCompatibleImage(GraphicsUtilities.java:37)
> at com.android.ninepatch.NinePatch.load(NinePatch.java:97)
> at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:430)
> at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:697)
> at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
> at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:126)
> at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:141)
> at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1394)
> at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1355)
> at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1330)
> at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:393)
> at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getDrawable(Resources_Delegate.java:184)
> at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:931)
> at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:810)
> at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat$Api21Impl.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:1110)
> at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:526)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:147)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:135)
> at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:66)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:83)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.(SearchView.java:306)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.(SearchView.java:276)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
> at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:293)
> at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:156)
> at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:117)
> at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:270)
> at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:426)
> at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:437)
> at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:341)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
> at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:358)
> at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:450)
> at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:122)
> at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:701)
> at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$8(RenderTask.java:848)
> at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:200)
> at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$PriorityRunnable.run(RenderExecutor.kt:298)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

and here is the problem with this "Failed to instantiate one or more classes"

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not find drawable resource matching value 0x7F070076 (resolved name: abc_textfield_search_material) in current configuration.
> at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1161)
> at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1137)
> at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1141)
> at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getDrawable(Resources_Delegate.java:187)
> at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:931)
> at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:810)
> at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat$Api21Impl.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:1110)
> at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:526)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:147)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:135)
> at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:66)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:83)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.(SearchView.java:306)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.(SearchView.java:276)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
> at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:293)
> at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:156)
> at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:117)
> at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:270)
> at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:426)
> at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:437)
> at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:341)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
> at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:358)
> at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:450)
> at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:122)
> at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:701)
> at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$8(RenderTask.java:848)
> at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:200)
> at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$PriorityRunnable.run(RenderExecutor.kt:298)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)